# store false boolean in array

Tags: php, arrays, pdo, boolean

I'm trying to store a false boolean into an array, to pass it as value in a PDO prepared statement:

```
$a = Array('bool' => '0');

if($a['bool'] === '1') {
    $a['bool'] = true;
}
else {
    $a['bool'] = false;
}

print_r($a);
```

The result is:

```
Array
(
    [bool] => 
)
```

I would expect:

```
Array
(
    [bool] => 0
)
```

Because if I store a true boolean value, the print_r function prints `true` as value of 'bool'.

Having the $['bool'] empty doesn't send to my **`bit`** field the false value and invalidates my query.

The value is passed with:

```
$sth->execute( $a );
```

How can I solve the problem?

---

For who says "use 1 and 0", well, PDO doesn't accept as boolean values the integers 1 and 0, it needs real booleans.

Comment: use integer 0 or 1 for false or true. It will work like boolean

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use 1 or 0 for true or false instead. Else, below is another way to do that:

```
if($a['bool'] === '1') {
    $a['bool'] = intval(true);
} else {
    $a['bool'] = intval(false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use integer 0 or 1 for false or true. It will work like boolean. You should to not use `===`  operator if you use integer as boolean.
you can simple test  like this:

```
if($intVar) {
     //do something it is true
}
else{
 //do something it is false
}
```

simply asign 0 or 1 in your array like this:

```
 $a = Array('bool' => 0);
```

then use it like this:

```
$sth->execute( $a );
```

It is not tested but should be work :)

Demo: https://eval.in/98660

```
 //test for false
  $a = Array('bool' => 0);


    if($a['bool']){
      echo "It is true";
    }
    else {
     echo "It is false \n";
    }

    print_r($a);

    //second test for true

    $a = Array('bool' => 1);




  if($a['bool']){
    echo "It is true";
  }
   else {
     echo "It is false \n";
  }
   print_r($a);
```

OUTPUT:

```
It is false 
Array
(
    [bool] => 0
)
It is trueArray
(
    [bool] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It does store the **boolean** value. So when you get the value you **should** expect a boolean value. If you use `var_dump($a)` instead of print_r you will see that it is stored perfectly as

```
array(1) {
  'bool' =>
  bool(false)
}
```

Comment: yes but if I store a true value it is printed out using print_r, instead if is false is not printed.